# Dynamic component loader - shared service for the resolving components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, dynamic-loading

I have to use [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) to add components dynamically.
For my example, I have a modal window which I dynamically loaded after pressing some button on the view.
And code for this action like this:

```
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(XYZComponent);
let viewContainerRef = this.containerHost.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();
let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

let _XYZComponent = componentRef.instance as XYZComponent;

_XYZComponent.close.subscribe(() => {
    componentRef.destroy();
});
```

Every time when I would like to use this modal window I need to put the similar code, only with the different component name.

I would like to create a shared service for this but I can't find a good solution for my case I mean dynamically loaded components.

Any idea how to create a good service to the use this code?

Comment: Is this for the child components of your modal, right?

Comment: @OsmanCea Yes, you right.

Comment: I've done something similar before but before I try to post an answer I wan to know something. How are you designing your modal? Do you want to have one instance of the modal component in your whole application? Or perhaps you want to span multiple instances and then create the content of the corresponding modal dynamically?

Comment: @OsmanCea I have one instance of the modal component in my application.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's all I needed to know. I'll be posting an answer in the next hour or two.

Comment: @OsmanCea thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will be loading components dynamically, you have to register these components somewhere, and that is inside the `entryComponents` of your modal component decorator. Also, since these components are typescript `class`es, you need to import them from whatever component you're calling your modal. In order to handle this in just one place, we're going to import these into a single file and then export them inside an array.

So here you will keep all the possible dynamic components, lets call this file `dynamic-components.ts`:

```
import { FooComponent } from './path/to/foo';
import { BarComponent } from './path/to/bar';
import { BazComponent } from './path/to/baz';

// export all dynamic components
export const dynamicComponents = [
  FooComponent, BarComponent, BazComponent
]
```

Then in your modal component, you can spread these components into the `entryComponents` property

```
import { dynamicComponents } from './path/to/dynamic-components';
@Component({
  //...
  entryComponents: [ ...dynamicComponents ]
})
export class ModalComponent {}
```

So far this should be all known to you.

Now, inside your modal component, you can create a method that will render a component taking as parameter the component name and also some metadata to handle props dynamically, by props I mean `@Input()` and `@Output()` decorated properties. This will make your modal more flexible, since you will be able to render components with different inputs and outputs.

So instead of hardcoding the component in the method like you're doing now, you'll have to extract it from the `dynamicComponents` array.

Since Javascript classes are sugar syntax for functions, all non-anonymous functions have a `name` property, this way you can match the name parameter provided by your function with the name of the components in `dynamicComponents`.

```
export class ModalComponent { 
  //...
  createComponent(name: string, metadata: any) {
    const viewContainerRef = this.entryContainer.viewContainerRef;
    const cmpClass = dynamicComponents.find(cmp => cmp.name === name);
    const cmpToCreate = new DynamicComponent(cmpClass, metadata);

    const componentFactory = this.cmpFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(cmpToCreate.component)

    viewContainerRef.clear();

    const cmpRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);


    // patch input values ...
    for ( let input in metadata.inputs ) {
      if ( metadata.inputs.hasOwnProperty(input) ) {
        cmpRef.instance[input] = metadata.inputs[input];
      }
    }


    // and subscribe to outputs
    for ( let output in metadata.outputs ) {
      if ( metadata.outputs.hasOwnProperty(output) ) {
        console.log('hasOuput', metadata.outputs[output]);
        cmpRef.instance[output].subscribe(metadata.outputs[output]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A couple things to mention. Here's the definition for the `DynamicComponent` class:

```
export class DynamicComponent {
  constructor(public component: Type<any>, data: any) {}
}
```

The reason for creating this helper class, is because `resolveComponentFactory` is expecting a component parameter with `Type<T>`, and the result of `dynamicComponents.find()` is a union type, so if we don't want the typescript compiler to complain, we should *patch* this class.

The rest of the function is pretty much what you have, except for the `metadata` parameter. Now, if the components you are instantiating in your modal have inputs and outputs, unless you design these components specifically to meet some criteria, might have different inputs and outputs. So that's what the metada parameter is, just an object with inputs and outputs. I guess it's clearer when you actually call the method, like this:

```
export class SomeComponentThatRendersTheModal() {
  renderFooComponent() {
    // I don't know how you call your modal, so I'll just assume there's a modal service or whatever
    this.modalService.openModal();
    this.modalService.createComponent(
      'FooComponent', { 
        inputs  : { fooInputTest  : 'kitten' },
        outputs : { fooOutputTest : handleOutput } 
      }
    );
  }

  // You can pass this method as the subscription `next` handler
  handleOutput(emittedEvent) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Where `FooComponent` is something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: `
    <h1>Foo Component, here's the input: " {{ fooInputTest }} "</h1>
    <button (click)="fooOutputTest.emit('Greetings from foo')">Foo output test</button>
  `
})
export class FooComponent {
  @Input()
  fooInputTest: any;

  @Output()
  fooOutputTest: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

Now, of course you can change the way the `metadata` looks or how you handle patching the input values or what you pass as handlers to the outputs, but this is the basic foundation of how you can create a different components dynamically.

---

Of course I've set up a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-components-angular) too. Hope it helps.

**12/14/07 Edit:**

Apparently accessing the `name` property of a `Function` object doesn't really work for production (you'll get a no component factory found error), since after uglyfying your code, the names of function get mangled and won't match. There's an issue comment on the [angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6454#issuecomment-315431370) explaining some workarounds for this problem.