# Dynamically ddd components by name from API to page in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm an Angular beginner and have a project to add components dynamically on a page based on certain rules using the component name returned from a web API. Basically, a user can click a button to add new component A, B, C, D, etc. I then have to check if they can add that component based on a previously added component and then add the component. Since the components are unknown, we defined the names in the DB, but I have seen so many different and somewhat confusing ways for doing something like this in Angular 2.

I have seen several examples online and Plunkr for adding components dynamically to an angular page using the **ComponentFactoryResolver**, but it requires the child components to be predefined in the parent class, but in my case I can't do that. Most examples required hard coding the child component name. Any way to reference the previous dynamically added component, and also add a new component by name received by an API in Angular 2? I'm not sure if that's realistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually know what was the previously created component as long as you have a reference to the `ViewContainerRef` where it was created. You could also create a service that will store the name of the created components and base your logic on that reference, so that part is no big deal.

Thing is, however, you have to tell Angular somehow that there are some components which are not declared in your markup and that will be created at runtime, that's why you have to pass these component `class`es to the `entryComponents` property of the component where you're instantiating your dynamic components. If you don't do this, Angular is just gonna ditch them and will not be aware that they actually exist.

So, short answer:

1. **Yes**, it is possible to create components dynamically based on custom logic related to previously created components.
2. **Yes**, it is possible to create components based by a name received in an API call, however, these components must be defined previously in your Angular application, and you have to pass them as `entryComponents` to the component where they are being instantiated.
3. How to do it? Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754534/dynamic-component-loader-shared-service-for-the-resolving-components/47759687#47759687), it's basically abstracting the logic of creating a dynamic component, so you only have to pass the component name and props.

If you need help with the first point though, try to setup a quick example and I can help with that.

Comment: Thanks Osman. I had thought there was a way to place components in a folder and have angular discover it at run time, in which case outside of bundling. That way I can add new components which needing to recompile the application, but I guess not. I should be able to do the first part from your explanation, and seems I have to register the component names before I can use it. I will be able to continue from here. thanks.